# why specifying space between buttons in linear layout doesn't work?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I want some space between two buttons in my layout, but for some reason, my xml doesn't seem to work.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAnswer_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/T1_Ans1"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@color/answerRed"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAnswer_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/T1_Ans2"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@color/answerBlue"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: If you mean the `layout_marginTop` isn't working, remove the `layout_margin` attribute, and set each side individually.

Comment: oh, my bad, missed that one, it works now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this :--

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAnswer_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/T1_Ans1"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="@color/answerRed"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAnswer_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/T1_Ans2"
    android:background="@color/answerBlue"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Padding will not change the separation between two elements. It will only change separation of text etc of an element from the element's boundary

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAnswer_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/T1_Ans1"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@color/answerRed"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAnswer_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/T1_Ans2"
        android:background="@color/answerBlue"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```